# Who all have the authority to blow the conchshell?

Tags: mahabharata, war

**Bg 1.12** — Then Bhīṣma, the great valiant grandsire of the Kuru dynasty, the grandfather of the ﬁghters, blew his conchshell very loudly, making a sound like the roar of a lion, giving Duryodhana joy.

**Bg 1.13** — After that, the conchshells, drums, bugles, trumpets and horns were all suddenly sounded, and the combined sound was tumultuous.

**Bg 1.15** — Lord Kṛṣṇa blew His conchshell, called Pāñcajanya; Arjuna blew his, the Devadatta; and Bhīma, the voracious eater and performer of herculean tasks, blew his terriﬁc conchshell, called Pauṇḍra.

**Bg 1.16-18** — King Yudhiṣṭhira, the son of Kuntī, blew his conchshell, the Ananta-vijaya, and Nakula and Sahadeva blew the Sughoṣa and Maṇipuṣpaka. That great archer the King of Kāśī, the great ﬁghter Śikhaṇḍī, Dhṛṣṭadyumna, Virāṭa, the unconquerable Sātyaki, Drupada, the sons of Draupadī, and others, O King, such as the mighty-armed son of Subhadrā, all blew their respective conchshells.

My question is in an epic battle like the ***Mahabharata*** who all had the authority to blow the conchshell? What exactly does it signifies?

Comment: Significance is asked in this question [What was the significance of blowing (sounding of) the transcendental conch-shells in the Kurukshetra war?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6611/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Significance is same for everyone who blows conchshell or is it different for each one?